# Which PE viewer application do you prefer to use when working with Win32 libraries?

Tags: c#, vba, dll, com, winapi

Which PE viewer application do you prefer to use when working with Win32 libraries?

I've previously used dependancy walker, but was wondering if better tools were preferred and for what reasons (such as features if you know of them)?

I'm not necessarily a C++ programmer, but have primarily used win32 functions in the past in VBA, VB6 and most recently C# projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency Walker, which is still a present day work-hourse, deals with meta-data of the binaries.  There are also fantastic tools for run-time concerns such as [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx).  Look a Process Explorer as one example.

Comment: good point about Process Explorer, except correct me if I'm wrong but it doesn't let you look at the function signatures? I ideally wanted something that shows both the function names and parameters as a minimum.

Comment: Yes that's true. Process Explorer doesn't show imports or exports.